Question about delaying integrator in verilog for PI filter in ADPLL
I am new to verilog and I would like an advice I am trying to do a PI filter for ADPLL from the book :All digital frequency synthesizer in cmos from Staszeweski
the integrator has H(z) =
a (scalar) *z^(-1)
1-z^(-1)
thank you in advance
my code is this:
module adpll_integrator (
    input                         i_clk,                                          // Input clock
    input                         i_rst_an,                                       // Asynchronous active low reset
    input                         i_en,                                           // Registers enable
    input    [3:0]                i_mul_a,                                        // Input multiplier a

    input   signed [31:0]         i_phase,                                        // Input phase difference
    output  signed [31:0]         o_phase                                         // Output phase
);
     wire signed [31:0] s_mul_a
     assign s_mul_a = i_phase >>> i_mul_a;
    always @(posedge i_clk or negedge i_rst_an) begin
        if(~i_rst_an) begin
            o_phase <= 32'd0;
        end
        else if (i_en) begin
            o_phase <= $signed(o_phase) + s_mul_b;
        end
    end

